# Is a package's help index page customizable?

Tags: r, roxygen2

The `help()` function allows us to see an index with a list of all functions within a package:

```
help(package=stats)
```

If the package is very large, the help page will be automatically broken down alphabetically, with links to each section by initial letter (as in the case of `stats`). Smaller packages will have all the functions together in alphabetical order.

Is this index page customizable?

I'm using `roxygen2`, and would love to be able to group functions by their `@family`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See section 10.6 of [R Packages](https://r-pkgs.org/man.html) :

> You can use roxygen to provide a help page for your package as a whole.

> you need to document NULL, and then manually label it with @docType package and @name . This is also an excellent place to use the @section tag to divide up page into useful categories.

Just create an `mypackage.R` file with the above `Roxygen` tags applied to `NULL`:

```
#' Mypackage: A package I created
#'
#' MyPackage has different families of functions described below
#' 
#' @section Some functions:
#' * [mysum()] 
#' * [myprod()]
#' 
#' @section Other functions:
#' * [other()]
#' * [foo()]
#'
#' @docType package
#' @name mypackage
NULL
```

The brackets `[]` allow to create links to the functions of the package.

Comment: While not an exact answer to my question (whether the index could be customized, not the "package overview" page), I suspect this is what's possible (and arguably better, since `?mypackage` is probably used more often than `help(package=mypackage)`).